# If an animation is run on the same view twice, onAnimationEnd() is not called the second time

Tags: android, progress-bar, objectanimator

I am developing a basic app for detecting all the Gestures like (Single tap, Double Tap, Swipe, Shake). I also have implemented for wait. i,e until the animation is completed.

I am using Horizontal progress bar as timer using the **ObjectAnimator**.

For that i am displaying text like Single tap, and if any action other than this is done it is error.

So for the first time when WAIT text is displayed if I do not perform any action the **onAnimationEnd** is getting called.

Below is my code.

`objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(timerProgress, "progress", 0, 100);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(progressTime);
        objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        objectAnimator.setEvaluator(new IntEvaluator());
        objectAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                if (timerProgress.getProgress() != 100) {
                    return;
                }
                if (!isTouched) {
                    onTouch(Constants.WAIT);
                }
            }
        });`

If i set any text after WAIT, (say Double tap ) and if I do not perform anything, the **onAnimationEnd** must be called. But it is not geting called.

I have used **view.clearAnimation()** but didnt work.

Is there any work around.? Please help

Comment: `View.clearAnimation` if for the old animation system, that's why it doesn't do anything here. You also don't need to create an `IntEvaluator` in this case since the system can infer it from the method type. How do you start the animation?

Comment: i have a separate method for starting and cancelling the animation. startAnimation() { objectAnimator.start() }. and for cancel animation , cancelAnimaton() { objectAnimator.cancel() }